# MATLAB adding matrices with different dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm having trouble adding two arrays with different sizes. When I explored a bit on this site it seemed like most questions involved vectors with different sizes, but not actual matrices with multiple dimensions in both rows and columns.

I know it "doesn't make sense" mathematically to add matrices with different dimensions. It's just a tool I'm using to make code work easier, but here goes the question:

```
A = magic(4);
B = magic(3);
C = A + B
```

That is basically what I want to do. I just want to make B have zeros along the 4th row and 4th column, and then I could have the same dimensions and add them. But how do I do it? Thanks in advance =)

EDIT: Also, in particular I would like to add B to A in a way so the original 3x3 from A basically "moves over" 1 column but stays in the same row.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your edit. Care to give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pad the array B with zeros before adding A and B.
Use the function "padarray"

Comment: @A S Ahh! Thank you that is the perfect thing =)

Comment: @ASHmm...actually it's being a little difficult. The argument 'pre' for padarray almost does what I want, except I only one it to 'pre' in the column dimension and 'post' in the row dimension....I do not see a method to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Note that [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) requires the Image Processing Toolbox to be installed.

A native solution involving padding would look like this:

```
C = B;
C(end + 1:size(A, 1), end + 1:size(A, 1)) = 0;
C = C + A;
```

This assumes that matrix `A` is larger in dimensions than `B`, but you can easily modify this code if not.

An alternative to padding is adding the matrix `B` to the appropriate elements in `A`. This can be accomplished in a lot of ways, for instance:

```
C = zeros(max(size(A), size(B)));  %// Preallocate matrix to accommodate result
C(1:size(A, 1), 1:size(A, 2)) = A;
C(1:size(B, 1), 1:size(B, 2)) = C(1:size(B, 1), 1:size(B, 2)) + B;
```

This specific example computes the indices of the elements of `A` and `B` in the matrix `C`, and sums overlapping elements.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `A` may be re-used destructively, you can also accomplish it with direct indexing into `A`. This saves a dependency (`padarray`) and reduces the memory complexity to `O(N)` (instead of `O(N²)` for `padarray` or manual padding):

```
idx = {1:size(B,1), 1:size(B,2)};
A(idx{:}) = A(idx{:}) + B;
```

Or, for arbitrarily shaped matrices,

```
A(1:size(B,1),1:size(B,2),2) = B;
sum(A,3)
```

but I advise you to be **really careful** with all this, and at most use it *sparingly*. The fact that it is not possible natively is actually a *protection* against creating bugs. The dimensions of a matrix have mathematical meaning; trying to automate resizing by one of the standard operations *breaks* the mathematical rules, which more often than not is a fertile breading ground for bugs.

Comment: What if you don't want to modify matrix `A`? :)

Comment: @EitanT: then just say `C = A` and index `C` :)

Comment: and what if `A` is smaller in size than `B`? (Just nitpickin'... :P )

Comment: @EitanT or `size(A,1) > size(B,1)` and `size(A,2) < size(B,2)` (Just sayin'... :P )

Comment: @EitanT: Then just swap all occurrences of `A` with `B`...Look, the OP is doing something mathematically unsound; coming up with a nice short fast catch-all one-liner is kind of breaking all of the syntactical protections MATLAB has against things like this. Even if there were such a one-liner, I consider it safest to keep implementations of this sort of thing *simple* and *specific* to the use case, rather than generic and universally applicable (although I could gain a lot of reputation from questions on SO that would result from giving that advice...:)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Yes, I tend to agree with that. I was just wondering how this solution is any different from my second suggestion (except for being a bit neater the comma-separated list) I had no intention of irritating :)

Comment: @EitanT: I must admit I saw your solution only after I posted the second edit to my answer, so I apologize if it seemed I tried to hijack your post. And you weren't irritating me, just...stimulating me to conjure up good counterarguments :p

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Ah, no problem then. Great minds think alike, no? +1